# How does a capacitor pass the flow?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance

Capacitor has just two conductor surfaces which have no touch. How can it pass the electric flow when there's no touch between the surfaces?

Comment: It can not pass a current but can always transfer the field effects by rate of change of charging of plates/or by charging by a source  and discharging through a load.

Comment: For this question you need the concept of "displacement current", which is an essential part of Maxwell's equation. It was the last piece that fell in place in electrodynamics and it is one of the hardest to measure with precision. Essentially, what the concept tells you is that a temporal change in an electric field creates a "real" current, even though no actual charge carriers are moving along the path of the current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crudely: When negative charges accumulate on one capacitor plate, they repel electrons on the other plate and charge in motion is current.